# JSON - Blogger API - How to read text from a specific page?

Tags: java, android, json, google-api

Could anyone tell me how do I get the content of this JSON file?

...................................................................

Note : I just want to know how to read the **content** from the JSON.

...................................................................

[LINK TO JSON](https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOG-ID/pages/PAGE-ID?key=YOUR-KEY)

```
{
 "kind": "blogger#page",
 "id": "myId01",
 "blog": {
  "id": "myId02"
 },
 "published": "2018-02-17T03:43:00-08:00",
 "updated": "2018-02-17T03:43:59-08:00",
 "etag": "\"mytag\"",
 "url": "http://my.blogspot.com/p/page.html",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOGID/pages/PAGEID",
 "title": "page",
 "content": "STACK OVERFLOW",
 "author": {
  "id": "myId03",
  "displayName": "MyName",
  "url": "https://www.blogger.com/profile/MyID",
  "image": {
   "url": "//lh5.googleusercontent.com/link/photo.jpg"
  }
 }
}
```

I want to read the **content** from the JSON, my code (working).

..............................................................

```
private class GetText extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ProviderHTTP sh = new ProviderHTTP();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("content");
///////////////////////// I'M confused HERE /////////////////////////
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                            text = c.getString("text");
                        }

                        toast.setText(text);
                        tost.show();

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    ProviderHTTP sh = new ProviderHTTP();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
             String content = jsonObj.getString("content");
             Looper.prepare();
             toast.setText(content);
             tost.show();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And now it's working!

Comment: So `toast.setText(content);` ? okay let my try

Comment: if its ok ..mark the answer......@ArghadipDasCEO....or if you have any problem with let me know

Comment: String content = jsonStr.getString("content"); `getString` showing error

Comment: im unable to see your full json ..could u post all

Comment: I posted the full JSON

Comment: It's blogger api

Comment: the error is "getString" it's red from the code `String content = jsonStr.getString("content");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165329/discussion-between-al-tegani-and-arghadipdasceo).